# How to get the parent id in jquery and values of all elements in that parent?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i have a which looks like this

```
               <div id="Address1" class="span4">
                    <ul class="address-customstyle unstyled">
                     <a href="#"><i onclick="EditAddress(this.id)" id="2" class="icon-edit mrglft largesize">
                                 </i></a><a href="#"><i onclick="DeleteAddress(this.id)" id="Address1" class="icon-remove mrglft largesize">
                                                   </i>
                                             </a>
                                        <li>
                                 <label>
                         <strong>
             <u id="addressname">
                       asdasd
                  </u>
                </strong>: </label>
               <span>
                <p id="hno">asdasd</p>,
                 <p id="streetname">asdasd</p>,
                 <p id="city">asdasd</p>,<p value="1" id="state">Andhra Pradesh</p>
               </span></li></ul></div>
```

now when i click on EditIcon i have the id of this

```
              <i onclick="EditAddress(this.id)" id="2" class="icon-edit mrglft largesize">
```

now what i want is based on this i have to get the parent div and the values of its childrens

like values of all "p" elements and value of "u" can any one tell me how can i do this

this waht i am doing for now but its not going in the loop

```
     function EditAddress(addressid) {
    alert(addressid);       
    alert(addresses);
    $("" + "#" + addressid + "").parent('.span4').find('p').each(function () {
        var $span = $(this);            
        var spanId = $span.attr('id');
        alert(spanId);
        var spanTxt = $span.text()
        alert(spanTxt);
    });
```

Comment: Your indentation in the HTML makes it hard to follow, not to mention how badly formed the HTML is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do like this, It will reduce the looping level.

```
var spanElem = $("#" + addressid).closest(".span4");
$("p", spanElem).each(function (){
   var $p = $(this);
   alert($p.attr("id"));
   alert($p.text());
});
```